# Typescript union type generic parameter

Tags: typescript, generics, union-types

So I have the following code sample:

```
interface MyInterface<T> {
  myFunc(value: T): void;
}

class MyImplementation implements MyInterface<number> {
  myFunc(value: number): void {
    console.log(value / 2);
  }
}

function myTest(): MyInterface<number|string> {
  return new MyImplementation(); // doesn't look quite right
}

myTest().myFunc("I am not a number"); // outputs NaN
```

I can't quite get my head around why typescript is allowing me to return ***MyImplementation***
in place of ***MyInterface<number | string>***. I understand we want ***number*** to be assignable to ***number | string*** but surely not for generic parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example also works without generics:

```
interface MyInterface {
  myFunc(value: number): void;
}

interface MyInterface2 {
  myFunc(value: number|string): void;
}

class MyImplementation implements MyInterface {
  myFunc(value: number): void {
    console.log(value / 2);
  }
}

function myTest(): MyInterface2 {
  return new MyImplementation(); // doesn't look quite right
}

myTest().myFunc("I am not a number"); // outputs NaN
```

Typescript was designed to have some unsoundness in the type system as described here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

To work around this, you can define your interface like this:

```
interface MyInterface<T> {
  myFunc: (value: T) => void;
}
```

And then enable `strictFunctionTypes` or `strict` in your `tsconfig.json`.

See also: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html

> The stricter checking applies to all function types, except those
> originating in method or constructor declarations. Methods are
> excluded specifically to ensure generic classes and interfaces (such
> as Array) continue to mostly relate covariantly.

Comment: Thank you for the crystal clear answer. Declaring the function as a property rather than a method did the trick having already --strict enabled in my typescript config.